# How to show (the contents of) a subdomain as a path/subfolder with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, devops, ghost-blog

I have 2 websites:

- api.example.com (a Django app)
- example.com (a blog with Ghost)

This is my current nginx setup for my blog (root domain)

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

server_name example.com

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

# this was created by ghost one click deploy on DigitalOcean
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2369;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that I can go to `example.com/api` and see the contents of `api.example.com`, but am not redirected and the url in the addressbar should show `example.com/api`.

I don't even know the right term for this.. Proxying? Masking?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called reverse proxying. Try this config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name example.com;
    resolver <some_name_server_ip_here>;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2369;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_set_header Host api.example.com;
        proxy_pass http://api.example.com;
    }
}
```

If you specify your backed `api.example.com` with domain name, you'll need to add a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive to your `server` config. Or you can specify it with an IP address and do not use a `resolver` directive. Anyway you'll need to explicitly specify your api backend server name with `proxy_set_header` directive. You can use your local name server as `resolver` directive parameter if you have one, or use something external like Google public DNS (8.8.8.8) or DNS provided for you by your ISP.